# Regex get IP from Wireguard conf file

Tags: regex, grep, wireguard

To automate the deployment of our Wireguard VPN connection I need a Regex expression to get the assigned IP for a user in the configuration file for Wireguard.

The file looks like this, with a Block for each user:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ***********
Address = 10.0.0.1
ListenPort= ***
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK name1.lastname1
[Peer]
PublicKey = ******
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK name1.lastname1
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK name2.lastname2
[Peer]
PublicKey = ******
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK name2.lastname2
```

I just want the AllowedIP returned for a spacific user.

By now I have something like this:
`name1.lastname1(?s)(?:.*?)AllowedIPs = (?s)(.*?)# END`

This somehow works on this site: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)
But if i try to grep it in the command line I don't get anything returned.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to use the `-P` option so you can use PCRE features?

Comment: Note that `grep` operates a line at a time. You can't use a regular expression that matches across multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -A4 "^# BEGIN.*name1.lastname1" CONFIGFILE | grep "^AllowedIPs" | cut -d " " -f3
```

This solution will show only the first IP and assumes the user config block contains the IP within the first 4 lines. (you should adjust the `A4` after checking the variance).

1. By the fist `grep` the relevant part of the user block is is isolated, containing only one line with an IP declaration.
2. By the second `grep` the result is limited to the line with the IP
3. The `cut` eliminates everything except the first IP in the line.

---

Using `awk` would give better control for more reliable results.